# LINQ to XML in VB - attribute name is reserved word?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

Apologies if this has already been answered - I have seen a similar question for PHP but my issue is specifically for VB.

I have some XML that looks like this:

```
<artist ...>
  <name>XYZ</name>
  <relation-list target-type="artist">
    <relation type-id="5be4c609-9afa-4ea0-910b-12ffb71e3821" type="member of band">
      <target>0dfd6aab-9056-4764-89b0-80bee7c9f998</target>
    </relation>
    ...
  </relation-list>
  </relation-list target-type="url">
    <relation type-id="29651736-fa6d-48e4-aadc-a557c6add1cb" type="wikipedia">
      <target id="713a661b-b33a-4e91-95b3-05e679ab8506">http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Who</target>
    </relation>
    ...
  </relation-list>
</artist>
```

I want to extract all the relations within a relation-list of a specified target-type. So I thought it would be relatively easy to have a Where clause similar to the following:

```
Dim artistrels = From u In response...<relation-list> _
                 Where u.@target-type = "artist"
                 Select ...
```

But VS2012 does not like u.@target-type so I guess that target-type is somehow a reserved word. I have tried using all sorts of ways of specifying the name as a literal (double quotes, square braces etc) and haven't yet found a way of doing this (oh for a comprehensive Linq language syntax reference somewhere!). Does anyone have an answer to this one?

Answer (score 0):

`-` is a problem here. You have to put your attribute name in `<>`:

```
Dim artistrels = From u In response...<relation-list> _
                 Where u.@<target-type> = "artist"
                 Select ...
```